# Maxwell's Equations: Light as a wave in an electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

What does it mean for light to act as a wave in an electromagnetic field? How does an electromagnetic field propagate the information that a change in current has occurred in the form of light waves?

I understand that electrons release photons when they change velocity, and that this may be achieved by alternating the electron flow (changing the current). I would like to understand how these photons act as a wave to propagate the new state of the electron flow to a location far away from the electrons themselves, where the previous state of the electron flow still exists.

Thank you!

Comment: When we talk light as a wave nature, we dont imagine it to be photons or any particle as such. Its just a wave. Continuous or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a changing magnetic field at a point in space,  a curl in the electric field  is generated instantaneously,  $$\nabla × \vec{E} =- \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} $$ There is no inherit time delay in this equation, at a point, this change happens simultaneously.

This change at a single POINT happens simultaneously, however the superposition of all of these, act as though changes to the field ( as a result of an accelerating charge) over a DISTANCE, does take time.

Actually doing the mathematics, can often lead to a better understanding of the reality  without having to picture anything in your head  ( although less pleasing).

Doing so, indicates that the electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)$ of a charge, is dependant on  $\rho(\vec{r},t_{r})$.

where $t_{r} = t -\frac{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}{c}$

what does $t_{r}$ represent?

The second term represents how much time it would take for an object  at $\vec{r'}$ going at c m/s to  reach $\vec{r}$, meaning minusing that from that time we are evaluating the field at , would represent me evaluating my charge density, in the PAST by the exact amount of time it takes light to reach me, aka any changes to my charge density, won't affect the field, until light has time to reach it.

An electromagnetic wave is the mechanism by which changes are communicated to the field. The speed at which this happens is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}} $ or "c"

Comment: I have waited over 4 years for an answer like this! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I should also point out, that most EM waves in nature are not sinusoidal, ( since most accelerations of charge are not sinusoidal) simply any function translated at a velocity of c,

Answer (score 1):

If your familiar with Maxwell's equations then you must know:

```
A changing magnetic field produces an electric field
```

```
A changing electric field produces a magnetic field
```

Following up, when a current in a wire changes the corresponding magnetic field also changes. This change in magnetic field causes an electric field to be produced.The electric field produced is such that it also changes. So another 
changing magnetic field is produced. Which again produces an electric field.

While this happens with each jump from magnetic field to electric field the wave moves forward. Hence it can travel a far distance before it is absorbed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by "The electric field produced is such that it also changes"? Wouldn't this produced electric field also change the original magnetic field that changed it? I don't understand how to establish a continuity here. Is there some delay in how an electric field responds (by changing) to a changing magnetic field?

Comment: @patrikperko I quite didn't get what you said but the magnetic field produced is a time varying sine wave which produces another time varying electric field and the subsequent loops have a phase difference in them. (but the magnetic and electric field have same phase in the same loop)

Comment: From what I understand, an electric field is simply "information about how charge is arranged." Therefore, when this charge arrangement changes, the "information about how charge is arranged" (a.k.a. the electric field) changes as well. How is this change in the "information about how charge is arranged" propagated to a far away location? What "carries" the "change in electric field" information to this far away place? Comparatively, the medium of a water wave (water molecules) "carries" the information of the "water wave" through the cause-effect movement of the individual water molecules.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be understood without reference to photons.

Consider a transformer, consisting of two parallel loops of wire.  A changing current in one loop produces a changing magnetic field threading through the other loop.  As the magnetic field changes, it induces an electric field (per the del cross E equation in Maxwell's equations).  The electric field induces an electromotive force in the second loop, which drives a current.  Similarly, the del cross H equation in Maxwell's equations says that a changing electric field  creates a changing magnetic field.  Changing E induces changing H which induces changing E, and so on---; and that is what an electromagnetic wave is all about.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I think the part I am having trouble wrapping my head around is how does the induced magnetic field not change the original (generated) electric field that produced it (which would, in turn, cause the change in the induced magnetic field to be different in the first place, making it impossible to have changed the original (generated) electric field). Is there some sort of delay by which an electric field induces a magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

In the fundamental understanding of "forces", the four fundamental interactions adhere their respective forces with a particle ... electromagnetism uses the Photon. Maxwell concluded light is an electromagnetic wave having such wavelengths that it can be detected by the eye. Other wavelengths exist but are invisible ,since their wavelength corresponds with energies we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

With something like a radio transmitting antenna, the classical theory works well.  The wire of the antenna contains electrons and protons. The protons have electric fields pointing out, the electrons in. Normally the resultant is zero, but if you introduce an AC current, the electrons oscillate. This is like shaking the end of a stretched rope. The electrons introduce an oscillating transverse component into their field which propagates out through the field.  At the same time, the AC current produces an oscillating magnetic field which wraps around the wire. The interaction between these two fields determines the rate at which the disturbance moves away from the wire. The disturbance will have a maximum in a direction which is perpendicular to the wire, and will not be detected in the parallel direction.  In much smaller systems, quantum processes become dominant.